# Question about read file from text file c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file like this:
25
19
36
24
23
52
29
and the last number is minus 1
Here is my code

```
int command;
int data;
ifstream myFile("c:\\temp\\input.txt");
if (myFile.is_open())
{
    while (myFile >> command )
    {
       
        if (command  == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            myFile >> data;
            cout << data << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

when the program read -1 the program will break. But I don't know Why it just read and output like this
19
24
52
and the minus 1

Answer (score 2):

Your program reads input two times, one is:

```
myFile >> command
```

and:

```
myFile >> data;
```

So, `data` is the value after `command`, and has no check.

Change your code to:

```
int command;
// no need for data
ifstream myFile("c:\\temp\\input.txt");
if (myFile.is_open())
{
    while (myFile >> command )
    {
       
        if (command  == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << command << endl;
        }
    }
}
```